# Recyclerview: Make the first viewholder item start with a little space from the top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

This picture hopefully should explain a bit about what I want to do. 
Please remember that the ViewGroup that both the textview and recyclerview is a **FRAMELAYOUT**.

[image]

I would like to have a recyclerview that `match_parent` to the **FRAMELAYOUT**. The `textview` that shows the word "Places" must be on top of the recyclerview. You can't see it from the image, but the `textview` has an `alpha` of 0.5 so that it is semi-transparent.

What I want to do is to make the `recyclerview viewholders`, which is the dark green item you see in the picture, start a little way under the height of the `textview`. This way, when the user scrolls the `recyclerview`, the items will gracefully scroll under the semi-transparent `textview`.

Is there a way to make sure that the first item in a recyclerview start a little way from the top of the recyclerview (i.e., the height of the textview) so that this effect can be achieved?

Answer (score 13):

you can  try it!!  `android:clipToPadding="false"`

> Defines whether the ViewGroup will clip its children and resize (but not clip) any EdgeEffect to its padding, if padding is not zero. This property is set to true by default.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 7):

Try item decoration for the first item only.

```
public class VerticalSpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int mVerticalSpaceHeight;

    public VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(int mVerticalSpaceHeight) {
        this.mVerticalSpaceHeight = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
            RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 1) {
            outRect.top = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
RecycleView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_home_recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

//add ItemDecoration
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(TOP_ITEM_SPACE));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. I will try this later.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a layout With same height of that TextView like

layout/header.xml

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/recyclerViewWidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/yourTextViewHeight"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

use this layout as header for RecyclerView.

Hope this will solve your problem.

**EDIT** :

I thought your layout is like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:text="@string/action_switch"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

if this is the case, using 'layout/header.xml' (i specicied above) as header will solve the problem. Because 1st item header is not visible as it is transparent. while scrolling 2nd item will go to up looks like moving behind the `TextView`.

**EDIT 2 :**

you could use another way also. include `layout/header.xml`' in your `RecyclerView`'s item's layout. as

```
<Layout ><!-- your item's layout -->
    <include layout="@layout/panel_icon_item"
            android:id="@+id/marginTopView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/yourTextViewHight"/>
    <!-- your layout code -->
</Layout>
```

in `getView` of `RecyclerView` `setVibility(true)` if it is item 1 else 
`setVibility(false)`

Comment: No it won't. Please remember that the viewgroup is a framelayout. If I did as you suggested, the recyclerview will not scroll under the textview - I cannot see the recyclerview under the semi-transparent textview.

Comment: Your solution would work but the problem is that I will be creating a fake 1st item in my recyclerview which becomes difficult to manage when your recyclerview is always changing, items being added by the user to the top, items being deleted etc.

Comment: ok that's cool. I think Mr. Sachet Bajracharya 's solution will help.